# Optimal way of handling large binary data in Android?

Tags: android, arrays, optimization, kotlin, rx-java2

In my app, I have a long-ish running task (up to 10-15 minutes) during which the app transfers large amount of data (up to 16MB) from a BLE device.

The current implementation uses RxAndroidBle for the async execution of the transfer, which happens using BLE's `NOTIFY` characteristic option - the app subscribes to the characteristic, and requests the data to be transferred, and the BLE device starts sending out the packets containing the data. Thanks to how `NOTIFY` is solved (the server, in our case the BLE device, will retry packets that do not receive a confirmation that it was received), I do not have to care about anything but continuously storing the received batches.

At the moment it is solved by incrementing a regular `ByteArray` (the project is in Kotlin) via

`data += received`

However during such a transfer, around the 6MB mark, the available RAM for the app drops below 20% according to the GC logs, and steadily decreases to around 10-12% by the time 8MB is transferred. I have not tried with a larger batch as anything larger is quite uncommon with the device in question, but it can happen.

I've tried replacing the `ByteArray` with a preallocated `ByteBuffer`, however according to the GC messages, it is not a considerable improvement.

Is there anything to try here, to optimize the assignment of the data, or is it likely that the reason for the memory drop is somewhere else?

Comment: Maybe store data on disk?

Comment: That happens after the data has been transferred. Another issue is an OOM that happens when these files are being processed - apparently processing 8MB of raw data into a ~30-40MB JSON needs 5-600MB of raw memory...